# How to install older version of Visual Studio Code on ARCH

Tags: visual-studio-code, arch

I want to install older version of visual Studio Code from this link:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions

On Arch system.

For example, I download this version: https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.74.3/linux-x64/stable, how to install downloaded version?